# Kubernetes infrastructure as code best practice

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Can anyone point me to the common strategy to setup a Kubernetes cluster according to the principles of **infrastructure as code** and **automatic deployment** for different developer teams with Git repos and an undefined CI/CD platform.

Let's say I am going to use Terraform to deploy a Kubernetes cluster on a hypothetical cloud service named QKS with a commonly used service, for example Apache Airflow, for which a public helm chart is available. There are two custom services (from two independent developer groups) to deploy named "apples" and "bananas".

I am struggling with the separation of responsibilities of different code bases. Which steps in this process can best still be done manually. A lot is being written about this technology, but I cannot find any articles on this issue in particular.

Answer (score 1):

This is my own proposal.

Have three git repositories:

- *my-infrastructure*: includes the Terraform files, the Airflow Helm deployment and deployment of two namespaces included access roles to these namespaces. CICD tracks for changes and deploys them on QKS
- *apples*: code base and corresponding helm template. CICD can deploy on the apples namespace only.
- *bananas*: code base and corresponding helm template. CICD can deploy on the bananas namespace only.
  [image]

Notes:

- subdivision of the cluster into namespaces [is obvious](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/);
- all secrets and authorization tokens for the namespaces can be created via Terraform using Terraform kubernetes provider.

  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/secret.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting kubernetes project for this called [**cluster-api**](https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/) that lets you create, configure & manage kubernetes clusters in a declarative fashion in a way similar to how we manage different resources in kubernetes itself. It defines new resources of different kinds like *Cluster*, *Machine*

e.g. You could define a cluster like this:

```
apiVersion: cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: capi-quickstart
spec:
  clusterNetwork:
    pods:
      cidrBlocks: ["192.168.0.0/16"]
  infrastructureRef:
    apiVersion: infrastructure.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha2
    kind: AWSCluster
    name: capi-quickstart
```

Of course you would need a starting / bootstrap kubernetes cluster where you will deploy this resource. This project is still in prototype stage, so use caution.

Check out the *cluster-api* repository on Github: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api